# Round / Around and USE OF EVER

Tags: word-usage

these small pieces have been going **round** the sun **ever** since.
 according to above context , could someone help me understand:
1) what is the difference between round and around? also
2)why **ever** is used in the above sentence?

Comment: It's generally recommended that you want a bit before accepting answers. I'm not saying your accepted answer is wrong, but first answers aren't always correct. See [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Round" and "around" are approximately equivalent, although **round**, or more properly **'round** is more poetic.

Because "since" by itself leaves the reader/listener hanging. You could get a way with just

> round the sun since.

but what's expected is either

> round the sun ever since.

or

> round the sun since then/that time.

"Since" indicates the beginning of a period. The astute reader/listener could figure out what that period is from previous context. But generally "ever" or "then" would be added to indicate explicitly what that period is.

Answer (score 1):

> Going round the sun
>
> Going around the sun

Just about the same meaning, in this context: orbiting. Somehow around feels slightly more formal, but we often can use either word when describing motion.

As a UK English speaker I feel comfortable using either of these phrases

> I went round the corner to the bookshop
>
> I went around the corner to the bookshop

I believe that in the US **around** is more commonly used.

The work **round** does have other meanings such as "a round of golf" and also "King Arthur had a round table" here **around** does not work.

There are also specialised uses of **around**

> I get around

meaning that I travel quite a lot, here **round** would not work; it's a rather idiomatic expression. However just to sow additional confusion the Beach Boys do sing:

> Round, round get around, I get around ...

this I think shows how closely related the two words are.

As for **ever since**, it's a somewhat idiomatic expression, widely used.

The general idea is of unceasing action started at some point in the past. The planets began to orbit the sun and once started have never stopped. We use **since** to refer to some particular time in the past, in your example there will have been some earlier explanation for how the "small pieces" were formed and began to orbit. Considering the time since that event, the pieces have been continuously orbiting they have been orbiting

> ever since

Comment: You might add that the Beach Boys tune includes both around and round in the lyrics.

Comment: Yes, I really should have done that ...